# adb works in terminal but not in android-studio

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, debian, adb

I am a little stuck, just setup my computer(debian 64bit) with android studio and adb.
I downloaded adb through [here](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/75-debian/280-debian-wheezy-android-tools-adb-fastboot-qtadb).

When I execute adb in the terminal it works, but in android-studio, it can't find my device.
The message is:
Waiting for device.
USB device not found.

Are there any specific tweaks I need to do with android-studio to have it detect my device ?
I have configured my /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
set my device in debug and accepted the computer connection (when I run adb shell I can successfuly access the device).

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: Please describe how you “execute adb”.

Comment: By execute, run it in the shell.
ex:./adb shell

Comment: See if you have more than one version of adb on your computer.

Comment: <br> [Here][1] I found one of the solution. Hope it help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722685/terminal-not-registering-typing-in-android-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try run "adb kill-server" from command line. After that Android Studio will automatically launch a new adb server process which should pick up your device correctly.

Comment: Hey man it was as simple as that ! That did it ! Thank you !
Had to run android studio as root. If I tried as a user it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722685/terminal-not-registering-typing-in-android-studio) is solution. Hope it will help you. It helped me.

It is possible to bypass the problem enabling the legacy mode in the terminal options.

- Launch a command prompt from windows (win+r and then type cmd)
- Right click on the title
- properties
- options
- check Use legacy console, then click OK
- Restart Android Studio