# Terminal not registering typing in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, terminal

When I open the terminal in android studio and type, nothing registers and the cursor stays put.

[image: Terminal screenshot]

The screen shot caught the cursor between flashes but it stays right by the > after app.
Someone else had the same issue 4 months ago here : [Android Studio terminal issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175827/android-studio-terminal-issue)

But no one came forward with solutions.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: i would suggest you to go through this post [duplicate answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104231)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This behavior is a problem related to an incompatibility between IntelliJ (and then Android Studio) and the new windows 10 console (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14354).

It is possible to bypass the problem enabling the legacy mode in the terminal options.

1. Launch a command prompt from windows (win+r and then type cmd)
2. Right click on the title
3. properties
4. options
5. check Use legacy console, then click OK
6. Close the terminal and open another one (or just restart Android Studio, it works both ways)

Comment: Worked for me, but I didn't have to restart Android Studio. You can just close the terminal session instead and start another. Thanks!

Comment: Whoa! works like a charm. But can anyone explain why does it happen to work after this ?

Comment: Android Studio 1.5 working now with non-legacy console (Windows 10 x64)

Comment: @mtrakal At least for Android Studio 1.5.1 and Windows 10 x64 I still need to have the legacy console

Comment: I am not able to see "Use legacy console option".

Comment: @Dhrupal, it's the last option in the cmd.exe properties. Check here: http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/enable-use-legacy-console-for-command-prompt-in-windows-10.html